# Vue 3 - Testing ref's focus() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vitest

I'm having some issues trying to figure out why my very simple test case keeps failing. I'm trying to learn how testing in Vue works and have very simple test, where `element.focus()` is trigger `onMount(() => /* see implementation */)`.

Here is my component:

```
const myInputRef = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  onMounted(() => {
    if (myInputRef.value) {
      myInputRef.value.focus()
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <input ref="myInputRef" name="my-input" type="text">
  <label for="my-input">input:</label>
</template>
```

and my test case:

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('should auto focus input element', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(App);

    const inputElement = wrapper.find('input');

    expect(inputElement.exists()).toBeTruthy()

    await nextTick()

    expect(document.activeElement).toBe(inputElement.element)
  })
})
```

The result is that, `expect(inputElement.exists()).toBeTruthy()` evaluates fine but
`expect(document.activeElement).toBe(inputElement.element)` results in:

```
AssertionError: expected <body></body> to be <input name="my-input" …(1)></input> // Object.is equality
```

[image]

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Is your `myInputRef.value` undefined? since I see that you set focus only if `myInputRef.value` is truthy

Comment: @rosmak? In the Vue Composition API, elements can be referenced as reactive variables using `ref()`, which is essentially an object where only the `.value` property is useful to developers. The object is automatically updated by Vue when changes occur. Everything is correct in the code. If you run it, you'll see that the result of `myInputRef.value` is correct, **but not that of `document.activeElement`** (only on test). Thus, **JavaScript did not update the activeElement property**, and the question was focused on why this is the case and how to address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Github Issue for enzyme.js (react) `document.activeElement`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2337#issuecomment-586583502)

Here we are discussing the same JavaScript issue, regardless of the framework and package.

The `wrapper` needs to be attached to the document body.

```js
const wrapper = mount(App, { attachTo: document.body });
```

- [Vitest Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-k6qe9c?file=test%2Fsuite.test.ts)
- [Vitest Playground Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNqOM.png)

If you comment out the line `myInputRef.value.focus()`, you will clearly see that the default value of `activeElement` is the body, due to the `attachTo` parameter.